# How to pass multiple params to function in python?

Tags: python, function, parameters

I am implementing 8bit adder in python. 
**Here is the adder function definition:**

```
def add8(a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,c0):
```

All function parameters are boolean.
I have implemented function that converts int into binary:

```
def intTObin8(num):
    bits = [False]*8
    i = 7
    while num >= 1:
        if num % 2 == 1:
            bits[i] = True
        else:
            bits[i] = False
        i = i - 1
        num /= 2
    print bits
    return [bits[x] for x in range(0,8)]
```

I want this function to return 8 bits. And to use this two functions as follows:

```
add8(intTObin8(1),intTObin8(1),0)
```

So the question is: How to pass 8 parameters using one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
add8(*(intTObin8(1) + intTObin8(1) + [0]))
```

Which concatenates the lists and then passes it as an argument to `add8`.

If you a doing this a few times you could put it in another function:

```
def add8_from_bin8(a,b,c0):
    add8(*(a + b + [c0]))

add8_from_bin8(intTObin8(1), intTObin8(1), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

You do not take 16 parameters in your add8. You take two list, each of 8 elements, if you want to do it.

Plus, in your intToBin you should use 0 and 1 instead of False and True; you should also check that the number can be expressed with 8 bit (if I call that function with 1000, what does it happen?) and you should name your function following PEP8 : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

ps are you aware that you can simply do `int(num, 2)` to convert in base 2?

Having said that, sometimes you can use tuple unpacking to simplify your code:

```
def f(a, b, c):
   bla bla

l = [arg1, arg2, arg3]
f(l[0], l[1], l[2]) #well it's awful
f(*l) #nice
```

Comment: The thing is add8() is written not by me. So I have to play with the rules they created. And I am noob in python :) Thanks for response

Comment: ah ok that makes more sense.. but please tell the writer of add8 to learn python :-)